# Need help in displaying image in PDF using XSL-FO and data URI scheme

Tags: java, image, xslt, pdf, xsl-fo

For the DATA, if i set the base64 encoded string in a parameter,

```
String imageData = Base64.encode(IOUtils.toByteArray(is));
transformer.setParameter("imageData", imageData);
```

and use the parameter in xslt like this,

```
<fo:external-graphic src="data:image/jpeg;base64,$imageData"/>
```

I tried with url and without url and both doesn't seem to work. Please help me. I am struggling to get the image on the pdf for over a month now.

Comment: Is your issue that you aren't getting the base64 encoded data inside of the attribute, or that your FO engine isn't properly rendering the data uri?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is your issue that the `$imageData` isn't being output with the values, just the string literal "$imageData"?

When you are inside of an attribute and want to evaluate the value of the variable, you need to use an [attribute value template](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates).  Wrap the variable with curly braces.

```
<fo:external-graphic src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{$imageData}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. It worked. Now that I have something working, could you please help me with a more efficient solution to add the images rather than having to read & convert image to bas64 string every time. This is what my set up is. I have the image which in in relative path to the xsl - images/pic.jpg I learnt that for the xsl to resolve relative paths, I have to set the base URL. But the default base URL is the domain directory which is 'C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects/domains/myDomain/'.

Comment: And when the application is deployed, it is exploded in the domain directory and the image I want is inside this folder - 'servers/myApp/tmp/_WL_user/agency/29k2yv/war/images'. If I set this directory as base directory, I am able to acces images just like this - <fo:external-graphic src="file:image.jpg"/> But the location will change in the QA and production environments and don't feel like hard coding a path which is outside the application ear. Is there a better solution for this?

Comment: Glad that worked. One idea to make it easier to obtain the Base64 content would be to create a servlet that you could pass the filename or URI as a querystring parameter that would return XML content with the Base64 value for that resource that you could XPath in and retrieve the content. You could reference those servlet URLs any number of ways (entity references, using XSLT `document()` function, etc.). The physical location of your files might change, but you could maintain a static servlet path `http://localhost/myApp/base64Servlet?file=image.jpg`